# shift -1 to sizeof(int) generates two different results in C++

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm writing some code and find this issue. I'm curious about why does this happen.

The code is as follows:

```
int n = sizeof(int)*8;
int mask_two = (-1<<n);
cout<<"1:"<<hex<<mask_two<<endl;

int y = -1<<(sizeof(int)*8);
cout<<"2:"<<hex<<y<<endl;
```

When I compile this code, the output is:

```
1:ffffffff
2:0
```

Why are the ouput #1 and output #2 not the same value? The compile is Visual C++ 10.0. What is the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, left-shifting *negative* values produces undefined behavior in C++11, although C++03 (and before) did not say that explicitly.

Secondly, you are not allowed to shift *any* values by their full bit-width or more. This is also undefined behavior. And that is exactly what you are doing: you are shifting an `int` value by bit-width of type `int` (assuming that `CHAR_BIT` is `8` on your platform).

The allowed values of shift counter in your example can range from `0` to `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1`. You are venturing out of that allowed range.

The difference in the results is probably caused by the fact that the first value was calculated at run-time and the second one at compile-time. These calculation algorithms worked differently on your input, which is why the result is different. This is OK, since the behavior is undefined anyway.